# Error While deploying in Oracle weblogic 11g

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, weblogic11g

During deployment of  my application in Oracle weblogic 11g
Messages

```
Unable to access the selected application.
Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
Exception in AppMerge flows' progression
All tags must be contained within a single element
All tags must be contained within a single element
```

Complete stack trace

```
Error at Line:3, token:[OPENTAGBEGIN]All tags must be contained within a single element
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseProlog(BaseParser.java:417)
    at weblogic.xml.babel.baseparser.BaseParser.parseSome(BaseParser.java:328)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.advance(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:195)
    at weblogic.xml.stax.XMLStreamReaderBase.next(XMLStreamReaderBase.java:237)
    at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(Unknown Source)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.DebugStreamReaderDelegate.next(DebugStreamReaderDelegate.java:89)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.BasicMunger2.next(BasicMunger2.java:442)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger._next(VersionMunger.java:333)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.next(VersionMunger.java:221)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.consumeInputStream(VersionMunger.java:499)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.init(VersionMunger.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:85)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.VersionMunger.<init>(VersionMunger.java:71)
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.WeblogicEjbJarReader.<init>(WeblogicEjbJarReader.java:34)
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.EjbJarDescriptor$MyWlsEjbJarDescriptor.createXMLStreamReader(EjbJarDescriptor.java:306)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.createDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:402)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBeanWithoutPlan(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:759)
    at weblogic.application.descriptor.AbstractDescriptorLoader2.loadDescriptorBean(AbstractDescriptorLoader2.java:768)
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.EjbJarDescriptor.parseWeblogicEjbJarBean(EjbJarDescriptor.java:164)
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.EjbJarDescriptor.parseEditableWeblogicEjbJarBean(EjbJarDescriptor.java:199)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.processWLEjbJarXMLWithSchema(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:732)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.parseWLDD(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:563)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.processWeblogicEjbJarXML(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:402)
    at weblogic.ejb.container.dd.xml.EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.createDescriptorFromJarFile(EjbDescriptorReaderImpl.java:184)
    at weblogic.ejb.spi.EjbDescriptorFactory.createDescriptorFromJarFile(EjbDescriptorFactory.java:73)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.EJBModule.merge(EJBModule.java:174)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.MergeModuleFlow.compile(MergeModuleFlow.java:23)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:69)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$CompilerFlowDriver.compile(FlowDriver.java:96)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.ReadOnlyEarMerger.merge(ReadOnlyEarMerger.java:49)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.mergeInput(AppMergerFlow.java:88)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.flow.AppMergerFlow.compile(AppMergerFlow.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$FlowStateChange.next(FlowDriver.java:69)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:41)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver.nextState(FlowDriver.java:36)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.FlowDriver$CompilerFlowDriver.compile(FlowDriver.java:96)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.runBody(AppMerge.java:157)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:158)
    at weblogic.utils.compiler.Tool.run(Tool.java:115)
    at weblogic.application.compiler.AppMerge.merge(AppMerge.java:169)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.merge(AppMerger.java:88)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.internal.utils.AppMerger.getMergedApp(AppMerger.java:63)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:181)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.model.internal.WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.createLazyDeployableObject(WebLogicDeployableObjectFactoryImpl.java:156)
    at weblogic.deploy.api.tools.SessionHelper.inspect(SessionHelper.java:661)
    at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow$2.execute(Flow.java:469)
    at com.bea.console.utils.DeploymentUtils.runDeploymentAction(DeploymentUtils.java:5000)
    at com.bea.console.actions.app.install.Flow.appSelected(Flow.java:467)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.invokeActionMethod(FlowController.java:870)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.getActionMethodForward(FlowController.java:809)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.internalExecute(FlowController.java:478)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowController.internalExecute(PageFlowController.java:306)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.FlowController.execute(FlowController.java:336)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.internal.FlowControllerAction.execute(FlowControllerAction.java:52)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:431)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.access$201(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:97)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor$ActionRunner.execute(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2044)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:64)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.ActionInterceptor.wrapAction(ActionInterceptor.java:184)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.invoke(ActionInterceptors.java:50)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors$WrapActionInterceptorChain.continueChain(ActionInterceptors.java:58)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.interceptor.action.internal.ActionInterceptors.wrapAction(ActionInterceptors.java:87)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:2116)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.processActionPerform(ConsolePageFlowRequestProcessor.java:261)
    at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:236)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.processInternal(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:556)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowRequestProcessor.process(PageFlowRequestProcessor.java:853)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.AutoRegisterActionServlet.process(AutoRegisterActionServlet.java:631)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowActionServlet.process(PageFlowActionServlet.java:158)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.process(ConsoleActionServlet.java:256)
    at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
    at com.bea.console.internal.ConsoleActionServlet.doGet(ConsoleActionServlet.java:133)
    at org.apache.beehive.netui.pageflow.PageFlowUtils.strutsLookup(PageFlowUtils.java:1199)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.executeAction(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:686)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.ScopedContentCommonSupport.processActionInternal(ScopedContentCommonSupport.java:142)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.scopedcontent.PageFlowStubImpl.processAction(PageFlowStubImpl.java:106)
    at com.bea.portlet.adapter.NetuiActionHandler.raiseScopedAction(NetuiActionHandler.java:111)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:181)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.raiseScopedAction(NetuiContent.java:167)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.controls.content.NetuiContent.handlePostbackData(NetuiContent.java:225)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlLifecycle$2.visit(ControlLifecycle.java:180)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:324)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walkRecursive(ControlTreeWalker.java:334)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.ControlTreeWalker.walk(ControlTreeWalker.java:130)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:395)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:361)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.processLifecycles(Lifecycle.java:352)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.runInbound(Lifecycle.java:184)
    at com.bea.netuix.nf.Lifecycle.run(Lifecycle.java:159)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.runLifecycle(UIServlet.java:388)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.doPost(UIServlet.java:258)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.UIServlet.service(UIServlet.java:199)
    at com.bea.netuix.servlets.manager.SingleFileServlet.service(SingleFileServlet.java:251)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at com.bea.console.utils.MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.service(MBeanUtilsInitSingleFileServlet.java:47)
    at weblogic.servlet.AsyncInitServlet.service(AsyncInitServlet.java:130)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:26)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.RequestEventsFilter.doFilter(RequestEventsFilter.java:27)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:56)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.doIt(WebAppServletContext.java:3684)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3650)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:121)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2268)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1446)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:201)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:173)
```

Sample weblogic.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<weblogic-web-app
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee  http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app    http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.0/weblogic-web-app.xsd" xmlns:wls="http://www.bea.com/ns/weblogic/weblogic-web-app" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<session-descriptor>
    <timeout-secs>2400</timeout-secs>
    <encode-session-id-in-query-params>true</encode-session-id-in-query-params>
  </session-descriptor>

  <jsp-descriptor>

      <keepgenerated>true</keepgenerated>
      <page-check-seconds>0</page-check-seconds>
  </jsp-descriptor>

  <context-root>/</context-root>

</weblogic-web-app>
```

My application.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="5">
  <display-name>Group Management System</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>appWeb</web-uri>
      <context-root>/appWeb</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
</application>
```

Kindly help me. When deployed in weblogic 9.2 it work perfectly.

Comment: The exception trace contains `WeblogicEjbJarReader`. Sounds like it's an EJB JAR XML descriptor that's failing.

Comment: also post `weblogic-ejb-jar.xml`

Comment: **<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd"> <enterprise-beans> <session> <ejb-name>Service</ejb-name> <home>MyHome</home> <remote>MyService</remote> <ejb-class>MyImplBean</ejb-class> <session-type>Stateless</session-type> <transaction-type>Bean</transaction-type> </session> </enterprise-beans> </ejb-jar>**

Comment: adding the following namespace i was able to get rid of the error but the second challenge is to expose this ejb as web service in weblogic 10.3.3. (aka weblogic 11g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anupum

Did you tried DDConverter? Its example as follows:

java weblogic.DDConverter -d tempdir my.ear

Reference 
[DDConverter examples](http://middlewaremagic.com/weblogic/?p=2772)

Comment: Yes it got change will a great help for people how migrate to higher version. old ejb-jar.xml DD `<ejb-jar id="ejb-jar_ID" version="2.1" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd">` new ejb-jar.xml after running the DDConvertor <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

`<!DOCTYPE ejb-jar PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Enterprise JavaBeans 2.0//EN" "http://java.sun.com/dtd/ejb-jar_2_0.dtd">`

Comment: I know I'm digging up a very old post but I've got the same error message as the above chap and have not understood your response at all. What is this DD converter?

Answer (score 0):

File **application.xml** wrong:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<application xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:application="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/application_5.xsd" id="Application_ID" version="5">
  <display-name>Group Management System</display-name>
  <module>
    <web>
      <web-uri>appWeb</web-uri>
      <context-root>/appWeb</context-root>
    </web>
  </module>
  <module>
</application>
```

Delete second tag:

```
<module>
```